# Is it really a memory leak?

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks, tomcat7, jstack

When undeploying my web application in Tomcat 7, the following message appears in the file catalina.out:

```
SEVERE: The web application [/myWebApp] appears to have started a thread named [Thread-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

I have used `jstack` to get a Java thread dump. I searched **Thread-10** on it, but I've not found any reference on this.

Is it supposed that something referring to ** Thread-10 ** should be there? Is that really a memory leak?

Comment: In apache Tomcat `manager` you can click "Find leaks" to find application instances that did not fully unload. If no application instance is found, that Thread-10 must have stopped and Tomcat was finally able to unload all data and classes of your web application. Nevertheless it would be adviced to find out who is starting threads in your application and how to stop them on application undeployment.

Answer (score 0):

The memory leak can happen when you war application starts a thread of its own that it wont make sure is stopped when the application gets undeployed. If that thread continues to run after application is undeployed it can reference active objects that will never be garbage collected because they are referenced by that running thread.